# Add/Remove item list

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing with `javascript`. I built a grocery list in which I would like to add and remove items. Adding elements works fine by typing a name in a input form and pushing the send button. I'd like to remove the element that I just created by clicking on it but I get this error instead:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of undefined at HTMLDocument.removeItem"

here the code:

HTML:-

```
<div id="paper">
    <h3 id="title">Groceries list:</h3>
    <ul id="list">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<p class="grocery">
    <input type="text" name="grocery" placeholder="ex. Apple" id="blank" />
    <label for="grocery">Grocery Name</label>
</p>

<p class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="btn" />
</p>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

CSS:-

```
#paper {
   width: 300px;
   height: auto;
   margin: 20px auto;
   clear: both;
   background-color: orange;
}

.grocery, .submit{
   text-align: center;
   margin: 20px;
}
```

Javascript:-

```
var elList = document.getElementById("list");
var elButton = document.getElementById("btn");

function addItem(e) {
   var elElement = document.createElement("li");
   var whatever = el.value;
   var elText = document.createTextNode(whatever);
   elElement.appendChild(elText);
   elList.appendChild(elElement);
}

function removeItem(e) {
   var elElement = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
   var elContainer = elElement.parentNode;
   elContainer.removeChild(elElement);
}

var el = document.getElementById("blank");

elButton.addEventListener("click", addItem, false);

if ("DOMNodeInserted") {
   document.addEventListener("click", removeItem, false);
}
```

How could I get through this?
Thank you guys for your help

Comment: Why are you calling add when you click the textbox?

Comment: "getElementsByTagName" returns an array, so get the nth item by accessing it by its index. E.g. elElements[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if ("DOMNodeInserted") {
   document.addEventListener("click", removeItem, false);
}` is wrong. you need to attach this event handler to each list you create.
you can do that in `addItem()` using `elElement.addEventListener("click", removeItem, false);`, then in `removeItem(e)` just use `e` to get current element using `e.currentTarget` and remove it.

This seems to work:

```js
var elList = document.getElementById("list");
var elButton = document.getElementById("btn");

function addItem(e) {
   var elElement = document.createElement("li");
   var whatever = el.value;
   var elText = document.createTextNode(whatever);
   elElement.appendChild(elText);
   elList.appendChild(elElement);
   elElement.addEventListener("click", removeItem, false);
}

function removeItem(e) {
   var elElement = e.currentTarget;
   var elContainer = elElement.parentNode;
   elContainer.removeChild(elElement);
}

var el = document.getElementById("blank");

elButton.addEventListener("click", addItem, false);
```

```css
#paper {
   width: 300px;
   height: auto;
   margin: 20px auto;
   clear: both;
   background-color: orange;
}

.grocery, .submit{
   text-align: center;
   margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="paper">
<h3 id="title">Groceries list:</h3>
<ul id="list">
    <li></li>
</ul>
</div>

<p class="grocery">
<input type="text" name="grocery" placeholder="ex. Apple" id="blank" />
<label for="grocery">Grocery Name</label>
</p>

<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" value="SEND" id="btn" />
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Dij, now it works. So If I attach the remove event listener to the add function it means that every new element will have the remove function attached, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
function removeItem(e) {
   var elElement = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
   var elContainer = elElement.parentNode;
   elContainer.removeChild(elElement);
}
```

This `document.getElementsByTagName` return an HTMLElementCollection which does not have the a property called `parentNode`. An element from that collection would.

To avoid the undefined error, you need to check if your object is null or undefined before trying to call a method on in such as `.removeChild`.

In your case, `elContainer` is null because the `elElement` is an HTMLElementCollection which doesn't have the `.parentNode` property.

You can access elements in the collection by index. It also has a length property which you should check to make sure that the collection has elements.

So if you want to remove the first LI, they you can do it like this.

```
function removeItem(e) {
   var elements= document.getElementsByTagName("li");
   if (elements.length==0) return;
   var elElement = elements[0];
   var elContainer = elElement.parentNode;
   elContainer.removeChild(elElement);
}
```

So if you want to remove the that last LI, they you can do it like this.

```
function removeItem(e) {
   var elements= document.getElementsByTagName("li");
   if (elements.length==0) return;
   var elElement = elements[elements.length-1];
   var elContainer = elElement.parentNode;
   elContainer.removeChild(elElement);
}
```